# Replace/add text in outlook email body

Tags: vba, outlook

I've got a folder with emailitems with a more or less structured format.
In those mails there is for example a line with: Cost: 1234
I wuld like to have some automated way that edits all those mails in this folder and adds AMT_ amount.
So the bodies of the mails need to be updated to (for the example above) Cost: AMT_1234.

Who can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

To process items in folder

```
Sub processFolder

    Dim oFolder As folder
    Dim oItem As object
    Dim oMail As mailItem

    Set olFolder = Session.PickFolder

    For Each oItem In olFolder.Items

        If oItem.class = olMail then

            'do stuff here

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To replace "Cost: " with "Cost: AMT_"

```
body = Replace(body,"Cost: ","Cost: AMT_")
```

If it is not that simple then Parsing Text From A MessageBody is described here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_ParsingTextFromAMessageBody

```
Sub FwdSelToAddr()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strAddr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        strAddr = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.Body, "Email:")
        If strAddr <> "" Then
            Set objFwd = objItem.Forward
            objFwd.To = strAddr
            objFwd.Display
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not extract address from message."
        End If
    End If
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFwd = Nothing
End Sub

Function ParseTextLinePair _
  (strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = _
              Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```

If you have a problem putting it all together you can create a new question that includes your code.